# failed to lazily initialize a collection of role only when sysout is not in use

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

i have noticed a weird problem. I'am gettin this exception:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.javacms.entity.Article.comments, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

With this code:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public List<Comment> getCommentsFromArticle(int articleId) {
    Article article = getArticle(articleId);
    System.out.println(article);
    List<Comment> comments = article.getComments();
    //System.out.println(comments);
    return comments;
}
```

But when i remove comment from System.out.println(comments) and code looks like this:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public List<Comment> getCommentsFromArticle(int articleId) {
    Article article = getArticle(articleId);
    System.out.println(article);
    List<Comment> comments = article.getComments();
    System.out.println(comments);
    return comments;
}
```

Code works fine, just like I suspect. Did anyone have this same problem. I dont understand why there is a bug when I'am not using sysout.

Comment: Because printing the comments initializes the collection while you're inside the transaction and the session is still open. Without it, the collection stays uninitialized and trying to initialize it outside the transaction, when the session is closed, can't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call article.getComments() ,hibernate will return proxy object . Unless you actually perform any operation on comments hibernate will not initialze it.
When you call system.println on comments toString() will get called on the object , hibernate get to know that you are performing operation on that object so it will initialize it as it is running in a transaction.
You can explicitely call hibernate.initialize(comments) . It will work fine

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to JB Nizet i removed a bug. Now code looks like that:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public List<Comment> getCommentsFromArticle(int articleId) {
    List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>(getArticle(articleId).getComments());
    return comments;
}
```